# Integral involving the fractional part function

Tags: integration, fractional-part, euler-maclaurin

Let $\{\}$ denote the fractional part function and $s>1$ be a real number,  then does the following integral admit a closed-form ?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x^s}\bigg\}dx\,$$

Comment: What do you get from $x = t^{-1/s}$ ? Do you know that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s\int_n^\infty t^{-s-1}dt = s \int_1^\infty \lfloor t \rfloor t^{-s-1}dt$ ?

Comment: @reuns, this substitution gives a similar locked integral.

Comment: I have got already a series representation of the integral in terms of Bernoulli numbers yet the question is if the integral could have a closed-form.

Comment: Can you show what you obtain from $x = t^{-1/s}$ ? ..

Comment: I have left an answer below

Comment: The solution is to do what I asked then use $\int_1^\infty  t\, t^{-a-1}dt = \frac{1}{a-1}$ to make $\zeta(1+1/s)$ appear. The closed-form values of $\zeta(s)$ is a well-known problem : zeros, negative integers, even integers, constant coefficient at $1$.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\int_{0}^{1}\braces{1 \over x^{s}}\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ s\ >\ 1} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ =\ t^{\large -1/s}}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over s}\int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{t} \over t^{1/s + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{1}{1 \over n^{1/s}} + {1^{1 - 1/s} \over 1/s - 1} -
\zeta\pars{1 \over s}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
1 - {s \over s - 1} - \zeta\pars{1 \over s}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{-\,{1 \over s - 1} - \zeta\pars{1 \over s}}
\\ &
\end{align}
In \eqref{1}, I used a
[Riemann Zeta Identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8).

Answer (score 0):

By applying the Euler-Maclaurin formula one may get the following relationship :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x^s}\bigg\}dx=\frac{s}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2s}+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\bigg(\frac{1}{s}\bigg)^\overline{2k+1}$$

Where $B_k$ denotes the k-th Bernoulli number and $x^\overline{n}$ represents the Pochhammer rising factorial. The question above could be transformed to finding a closed-form of the upper series.